# Why can't I connect to a remote Server because id_rsa

Tags: ssh

Here is what I see:

[image: ls]

I don‘t know why the id rsa in the directory `.ssh/ssh/`: Actually, it should be in the directory `.ssh/`  so system don't to find it.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do:

```
 mv /User/<you>/.ssh/ssh/id_rsa* /User/<you>/.ssh/
```

That would move those default keys to their expected place, allowing an `ssh -Tv ...` to work (while displaying where it is looking for those keys, and if it finds them)

If those files are *already* in the right `.ssh` folder, look for `~/.ssh/config`

Maybe in that file, you have a line with the wrong path:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ssh/id_rsa
# instead of
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That would also explain why SSH is looking for that key in the wrong path.